# selecting another element on input hover

Tags: css

Struggling to understand why this selector

```
.date input:hover .input-group-addon i{
color:blue;
}
```

will not change the colour of the icon next to my form input when I hover over it, it works if I select it's parent, but not if I select the form input.

```
.date:hover .input-group-addon i{
color:blue;
}
```

forgot to add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5m26w5ad/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS-selectors are hierarhical so you are looking for 
i, a child of  .input-group-addon, a child of input:hover, a child of date.

Look for neighbour css selectors

Comment: sorry i forgot to add a fiddle, .date is the parent of both elements.

Comment: @Goodsoup, look, when you write **.date input:hover .input-group-addon i**, you say that .input-group-addon is a child of input, that is not true :)

Comment: gotcha, i didnt realise i was trying to go back up the hierachy after the hover, doh!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the selector to -

```
.date.input-group:hover .input-group-addon i{
  color:blue;
}
```

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/5m26w5ad/1/